# Loop won't finish executing when a function is called within - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, function, for-loop

I am using the function below to create and link to a stylesheet in the `<head>` tag depending on which URL is passed.

```
function create(file) {
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.href = "https://example.com/" + file;
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    document.head.appendChild(link);
}
```

I have a for loop which won't stop running whenever the function is called.

```
    for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
          theFile = array[i];
          create(theFile);
    }
```

Within the `array` is just a list of CSS files - `"bootstrap.min.css", "font-awesome.min.css"`

I have tested out the function on its own and it seems to work fine:

```
create("style.css");  
create("style.css");
```

The code above manages to create two stylesheets in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: Hit f12 and open up your console. When things mysteriously stop it's generally because you have a js error that you need to clear.

Comment: @scrappedcola While going into dev tools is a good idea, I don't think the issue is something `stopping`. Clearly an infinite loop, I don't think there's enough code to really know that for sure, yet.

Comment: Have you tried making sure `i` is declared outside the `for` loop?

Comment: @scrappedcola Thanks for the response! I am unable to open it up though as the page just keeps loading so nothing appears in the dev tools.

Comment: `console.log(array.length)` please? Clearly it's an infinite loop, I'd bet a lucky dollar that you'd see this constantly writing in console.

Comment: @Osman It doesn't matter if it's loading, the console would still have things written to it.

Comment: @A.Duff Yep, doesn't seem to work

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet The console is blank for some reason and eventually I just end up with a "Kill page or wait" box. I can't get it to display anything

Comment: It's blank if you're not writing anything to it. But one good thing is that if it's blank, that means that there's no errors. Like I said, clearly an infinite loop. Can't really tell by your code, but try `console.log(array.length)` and I'd bet you'd see that in console quite a bit lol. Seems like a minor issue here, so that's good news.

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken btw? Usually you should have this information before asking question, so if you haven't, I'd try to debug the code and I bet you'll find the issue.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet How do you figure that array.length would be infinite, if you do that is?

Comment: It is possible your array is missing an element, so it starts out at zero fine, but somewhere in the incrementing, it is coming across an element that doesn't exist... example array[0], array[1], array[2], array[4]

Comment: @GaryHayes For real? Is that even a thing?

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet Without the for loop, that returns 13 as the array length. With the for loop leaves it blank when `console.log` is before the for loop.

Comment: For sure, I can't see your code, but if it is trying to load array[3], in my example, and it doesn't exist, you're going to have problems.

Comment: Ok so try `console.log(i)`. Pretty basic debugging that I'm asking of you, you really should be doing this on your own.

Comment: @GaryHayes He would be seeing JS errors in console, which he said he does not.

Comment: @AakashVerma The goal is to figure out what's going on. I think somewhere in his code is an infinite loop, he hasn't posted any more of his code so it's impossible to know. Just trying to guide him to learn how to debug to solve these issues on his own.

Comment: Perhaps a foreach loop would be better, or reassign keys first to make sure there are no gaps.

Comment: I hear you, @jdmdevdotnet . I'm just letting him know of some things to look out for, since we can't see his code. If the array is static, it shouldn't be an issue, but if it is dynamic, and some element is unset, he's going to have problems.

Comment: @GaryHayes Ok thanks! Turns out there was something wrong with one of the items in the array. They were pulled from another site and one of them had a `<`.

Comment: Guys! *gulp* I was trying something very silly.. Look at this https://ideone.com/ifCyaI Is the error similar? What is the error with my code????haha

Comment: @AakashVerma Nothing? https://jsfiddle.net/qLxkLbvc/

Although you should be declaring arr as a var.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet Okay pheww! The problem was that both console and alert functions are not defined on ideone and I was getting a ReferenceError. Hope you saw the code fail on ideone!

Comment: Good, glad you got it sorted.